# Bitcoin Client crashing while syncing

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

I am getting this problem today:

when syncing, the client suddenly crashes with the following debug.log:

.....
2015-06-29 14:30:34 IO error: C:\Users\Internet\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\chainstate\713704.ldb: Zugriff verweigert (access denied)

2015-06-29 14:30:34 *** System error while flushing: Database I/O error
2015-06-29 14:36:59 ERROR: ProcessNewBlock : ActivateBestChain failed
2015-06-29 14:37:00 net thread interrupt
2015-06-29 14:37:00 opencon thread interrupt
2015-06-29 14:37:00 dumpaddr thread stop
2015-06-29 14:37:00 addcon thread interrupt
2015-06-29 14:37:03 msghand thread interrupt
2015-06-29 14:37:03 Shutdown: In progress...
2015-06-29 14:37:03 StopNode()
2015-06-29 14:37:03 UPNP_DeletePortMapping() returned : 403
2015-06-29 14:37:03 upnp thread interrupt
2015-06-29 14:37:03 IO error: C:\Users\Internet\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\chainstate\713704.ldb: Zugriff verweigert (access denied)
2015-06-29 14:37:03 *** System error while flushing: Database I/O error

The message says client is stopping but the process never closes. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used windows.  But on GNU/Linux those access denied messages usually have to do with file permissions (because nonexistence usually says "no such file or directory").  The most typical case that I've seen is that you usually run this program as root and now you started it in normal user mode.